# Why a user can not see a production environment , even he is added to the environment security group

Tags: office-365, power-automate, powerapp, power-platform

I created a new Power Platform environment of type Production >> and i added a security group named "Prod users" >> then I added a user named "Test User" to the security group, as follow: -

[image: johnjohn123_0-1683770627268.png]

[image: johnjohn123_1-1683770690508.png]

but when I access the Power Apps or Power automate using the test user >> I cannot see the Prod environment >> and I can only see the default one as follow: -

[image]

so, any advice why the user cannot see the environment?

Thanks

Now when i check the user permission on the production environment using the "app access checker":-

[image]

I got this result:-

[image]

any advice?

Thanks

Comment: How much time you waited after granting permissions to user? It may take some time to sync the permissions and environment to show up. Wait for few hours and try login again. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for your help again, i waited now for around 10 hours did not fix the issue, still the test user cannot see the environment, does the last image provide any hint on why the user can not see the environment ?

Comment: Is this test user have either **Dataverse licenses or per app plan** license?

Comment: When I added my first comment above, I added one user in environment directly & granted **Basic User** role. Now that user account can see the new environment. I don't have access to production environment for now to test assigning security group to environment.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the reply, yes this is a test user but have "Power apps plan 2 trial" license,, so is this sufficient for the user to access the production environment ?

Comment: I am not sure if trial license will work here. If you have access to **per app plan** in your tenant, try assigning it for testing purpose - you can remove license later on. As per Microsoft documentation - *If a security group is associated with an environment, only users with Dataverse licenses or per app plan that are members of the environment security group will be created as users in the environment.*

Comment: @GaneshSanap ok understood let my try to test those at my end, granting the test user a permission is not an issue for me

Comment: Sure, let me know if granting per app plan license to test user works for you.